# Reopening class and adding instance variables

Tags: crystal-lang

I am teaching myself Crystal-lang and I came across a section in the documentation that I don't quite understand.

[Here](https://crystal-lang.org/reference/syntax_and_semantics/methods_and_instance_variables.html) is the documetation page.

On that page it gives the following code:

```
class Person
  @age = 0

  def initialize(@name : String)
  end
end
```

This is followed by the following statement:

> This will initialize @age to zero in every constructor. **This is useful to avoid duplication, but also to avoid the Nil type when reopening a class and adding instance variables to it.**

Can someone please explain, or show me an example of the bolded behaviour? I'm not certain I understand what it means by "reopening a class and adding an instance variable to it".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of reopening a class, and adding an instance variable to it:

```
class Person
  @age = 0

  def initialize(@name : String)
  end
end

# Usually in another file

class Person
  def gender=(gender : String)
    @gender = gender
  end

  def gender
    @gender
  end
end

person = Person.new("RX14")

typeof(person.gender) # => String | Nil
person.gender # => nil

person.gender = "???"

person.gender # => "???"
```

We add the `@gender` instance variable, which is not initialized in the `def initialize`. The compiler infers the type of `@gender` to be `String | Nil`, since it is assigned to a string in `gender=`, but it is not initialized in the constructor, meaning it can also be `nil`.

However, we can add a default value to the `@gender` instance variable, which applies to *all* constructors, define before or after the default:

```
class Person
  @age = 0

  def initialize(@name : String)
  end
end

# Usually in another file

class Person
  @gender = "unknown"

  def gender=(gender : String)
    @gender = gender
  end

  def gender
    @gender
  end
end

person = Person.new("RX14")

typeof(person.gender) # => String
person.gender # => "unknown"

person.gender = "???"

person.gender # => "???"
```

This avoids the `@gender` variable getting the `String | Nil` type, since it is initialized to `"unknown"` when `Person` is constructed. Since `Nil` types are often avoided, this is an important tool to have.